# Ways2sms SMS Service Showing Error connecting to the Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, sms-gateway

Recently I was trying to learn how to send sms using ways2sms gateway.

After I had successfully entered my UserName (ie my mobilenumber) & Password required for the authentication of sending sms through my mobile no.
Following error prompted: Error connecting to the Server.
What may be the problem:

I am facing Error at: Line

```
{ this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse(); }

try
        {
            this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwd.way2sms.com/auth.cl");

        this.req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        this.req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        this.req.Method = "POST";
        this.req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        this.strNewValue = "username=" + ckuser + "&password=" + ckpass;
        this.req.ContentLength = this.strNewValue.Length;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        writer.Write(this.strNewValue);
        writer.Close();
        this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();
        this.cookieCntr = this.req.CookieContainer;
        this.response.Close();
        this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwd.way2sms.com//jsp/InstantSMS.jsp?val=0");
        this.req.CookieContainer = this.cookieCntr;
        this.req.Method = "GET";
        this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();
        responseee = new StreamReader(this.response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        int index = Regex.Match(responseee, "custf").Index;
        responseee = responseee.Substring(index, 0x12);
        responseee = responseee.Replace("\"", "").Replace(">", "").Trim();
        this.response.Close();

        pnlsend.Visible = true;
        lblErrormsg.Text = "connected";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        lblErrormsg.Text = "Error connecting to the server...";
        Session["error"] = "Error connecting to the server...";
        Server.Transfer("login.aspx");


    }
```

Comment: What is the actual exception message

Comment: @ChrisBint The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: @Miles_To_Go_B4_I_Die Do you send unique identification id besides userid, password in request ? see here http://www.blog.openshell.in/2013/01/sms-api-to-send-sms-from-way2sms-part-3/

Comment: @Coder: The one you suggested was in PHP & I want in .NET (no matter in C# or VB)